# Logstash cant connect to Elasticsearch inside Docker -> Response code 401

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, elk

i am trying to **connect my Logstash Docker container to my Elasticsearch Docker container**.

First of all i will present to Elasticsearch configuration i am using:

I am running both services out of *separate docker-compose files* to manually be able to wait for one service to be ready etc. (just for now)

So here is my **Elasticsearch** `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.17.5
    volumes:
      - ./config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro,z
    ports:
      - 9200:9200 #API calls over HTTP - Maps the container port to a host port -> <host port>:<container port>
      - 9300:9300 #Custom binary protocol used for communications between nodes in a cluster
    environment:
      # Maximum amount of memory the JVm will allocate to a process.
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
      # Bootstrap password.
      # Used to initialize the keystore during the initial startup of
      # Elasticsearch. Ignored on subsequent runs.
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: elasticsearch
```

The `elasticsearch.yml` that is mapped to the inside of the container:

```yaml
---
## Default Elasticsearch configuration from Elasticsearch base image.
## https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/distribution/docker/src/docker/config/elasticsearch.yml

cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

## X-Pack settings
## see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html

xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: true

## Custom

# Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks.
# see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
discovery.type: single-node
```

The container runs!

The response from `curl http://elastic:elasticsearch@localhost:9200`

```json
{
  "name" : "a1d7acf92aa1",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "PstzFCUqRXKQx9WeD0-6WA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.17.5",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "8d61b4f7ddf931f219e3745f295ed2bbc50c8e84",
    "build_date" : "2022-06-23T21:57:28.736740635Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.11.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
```

I am noticing though that the service is in **status "yellow"** !

The output of `curl -u elastic http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health\?pretty`

```json
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
{
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 4,
  "active_shards" : 4,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 1,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 80.0
}
```

I am not sure if this has to do anything with logstash not being able to connect properly.

Now for my **Logstash** `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  logstash:
    image: logstash:7.17.5
    volumes:
      - ./pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro,Z #Mount logstash pipeline config into container
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "50000:50000/tcp"
      - "50000:50000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      # Maximum amount of memory the JVm will allocate to a process.
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: logstash
networks:
  default:
    name: elasticsearch_default
    external: true
```

The network of the Elasticsearch image default to `elasticsearch_default`, there is not network issue going on.

The `logstash.conf` that is mapped to the inside of the container:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }

    tcp {
        port => 50000
    }
}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "elasticsearch"
    }
}
```

Now when i start the Logstash container, i get following output:

```
ecreating logstash_logstash_1 ... done
Attaching to logstash_logstash_1
logstash_1  | 2022/07/25 09:22:01 Setting 'xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.ssl.verification_mode' from environment.
logstash_1  | Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
logstash_1  | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
logstash_1  | Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:10,864][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:10,870][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.17.5", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.20.1 (2.5.8) 2021-11-30 2a2962fbd1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.15+10 on 11.0.15+10 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:10,871][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -Djruby.jit.threshold=0, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true, -Dls.cgroup.cpuacct.path.override=/, -Dls.cgroup.cpu.path.override=/]
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:10,885][INFO ][logstash.settings        ] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:10,890][INFO ][logstash.settings        ] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:11,056][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"5dd7cac8-7d3f-4d24-8672-9c7bf445f893", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:11,565][WARN ][logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] xpack.monitoring.enabled has not been defined, but found elasticsearch configuration. Please explicitly set `xpack.monitoring.enabled: true` in logstash.yml
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:11,567][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and may be removed in a future release.
logstash_1  | Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at: 
logstash_1  | https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:11,791][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.codecs.plain] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:11,841][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:12,018][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:12,116][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:12,144][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:12,161][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:12,320][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,078][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 53 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 119 keys and 419 values 
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,501][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.codecs.plain] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,511][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.inputs.beats] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,553][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.codecs.line] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,558][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.inputs.tcp] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,575][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.codecs.plain] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,591][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,629][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,647][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,714][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,727][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch version determined (7.17.5) {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,728][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,773][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,774][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Config is not compliant with data streams. `data_stream => auto` resolved to `false`
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,796][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:13,817][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>12, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1500, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x765f0a97 run>"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:14,340][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.52}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:14,364][INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ][main] Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5044"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:14,467][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:14,473][INFO ][logstash.inputs.tcp      ][main][feac9b54ea188d2b2c8c296a8162a4fbc47d86d4390fe1ecf5e3d888b981444c] Starting tcp input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:50000", :ssl_enable=>false}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:14,495][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server][main][ab49b76e319e88922a61b48e46cf6f5e5fb830d4db168e3ce59a32926a48ae0d] Starting server on port: 5044
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:14,527][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:42,162][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_xpack'"}
logstash_1  | [2022-07-25T09:22:42,437][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping logstash_logstash_1   ... done
```

I guess it has to do something with the licensing ?? I already did a ton of research but i havent found anything that really helped me. I just want logstash to be able to authenticate using basic user/password login.

Any ideas ? Best regards.

Comment: Could you open a shell in the logstash container , and perform a curl request to `elasticseach` ? Are you able to acces the API ?

Comment: Yes i can connect to the elasticsearch container!

Comment: What command are you running from the logstash container ? COuld you paste it

Comment: `curl -u elastic http://elasticsearch:9200/_cluster/health\?pretty`  -> it produces the exact same response as i would expect it to do (see above)

Comment: Damm, It is not easy ... `401` means the credentials are wrong ... but you did double check that right ?